# Is there a way to detach/reattach the Frontend from a running Mathematica Kernel?

Tags: remote-access

I perform long calculations on a fast remote machine running the *Mathematica* kernel, where I followed the very useful guide [Remote Kernel Strategies](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7250/) to establish the connection. I wonder, however, if there is a way to detach the Frontend from the running kernel in the same way as one can use the Linux program screen to keep remote shell sessions alive. I couldn't find anything similar for *Mathematica*, even though such a feature would be very convenient. Is there a way of doing that?

Many thanks,

Andreas.

Comment: Unfortunately the front end isn’t supporting this in v12 - it may work but many dynamics and other things will most assuredly break, pinking and freezing galore!

Comment: If you have the option of running remote desktop sessions on the remote machine that would allow you to running the front-end on the remote machine as well,  then that would usually preferable. In this case the remote session manager will deal with the process of reconnecting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This comes a little late, but this is my solution:

Remote Machine running linux with tmux (similar to screen but newer, should work with screen but I dont know the commands) and Mathematica 10 installed.

Local Machine running MacOS Yosemite with Mathematica 10.

1. Launch tmux in remote machine and execute Mathematica:

   tmux

   wolfram (executable to mathematica in terminal mode)
2. Now create a link with TCPIP protocol. Record the linkname="linkPort1@remoteIP,linkPort2@remoteIP" generated.

   ```
   link=LinkCreate[LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"]                                
   LinkObject[linkPort1@remoteIP,linkPort2@remoteIP, 72, 1]
   ```
3. Now in local machine, start Mathematica and go to Evaluation->Kernel Configuration Options -> Add...    and fill out the window just as showed below.Dont forget to replace (insert remote ip ) by the remote machine ip address and insertLinkName by the link name that was generated above
   [image]
   clic ok. Then open a new notebook and set the above created kernel as the notebooks kernel. Dont evaluate anything yet in this notebook.
4. Go back to your remote machine and run

   ```
   $ParentLink=link
   ```
5. Finally go back to the notebook in your local machine and evaluate something:

   ```
   $Version
   ```

So now you are running the kernel in the remote machine with  the front end in your local machine.

6. To disconnect from the Kernel, evaluate the following in your notebook:

   ```
   LinkClose /@ Links[]
   ```

At this point your kernel is still running in the remote machine. To reattach follow steps 2 through 5.

This could be automatized with a script. Also if you know that a port is always available, you could set the link with a persisten name so that you dont have to reconfigure the remote kernel each time you attach.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried what you suggested, using screen on the remote host. It seems to work! Thanks again for stating the solution to this problem in such a clear way! Andreas.

Comment: Sadly this wonderful trick appears to crash Mathematica 12...

Comment: @Ranza Which operating system does it crash on?

Comment: MacOS Mojave connecting to Linux Remote

Comment: @Ranza you should email support@wolfram.com with the crash information, so they can investigate and hopefully fix the issue (if you are so inclined)

Comment: Thanks, @user6014. The idea passed my mind but I thought this might be too non-standard for Wolfram support. Anyway, let's see!

Comment: @Ranza Crashes are always worth reporting IMO. Who knows where else they might manifest!

Answer (score 2):

I have not done this before, but here's how I would approach this:

run the kernel on the remote machine from the command line using the 'background process' approach (i.e. '&' or "start")...

then run a script that will dump out the Mathlink connection id (or equivalent)...pass this to the front-end you want to be the client and start/restart the Mathlink connection...

Comment: Hm, okay, thank you, I might try that. I will report on the outcome later. Andreas.

Answer (score 0):

Again, use `tmux` to launch the background program. Run

```
wolfram
```

then

```
In[1]:= Import["launch.m"]
In[2]:= createLink[]
```

where `launch.m` file is the following:

```
createLink[] :=(link=LinkCreate["1113,51113",LinkProtocol -> "TCPIP"];$ParentLink=link;)
changeFormatType[] :=SetOptions["stdout", FormatType->OutputForm];
detach[] := (LinkClose /@ Links[]; createLink[];)
```

In Kernel configurations MLopen arguments are

```
-LinkMode Connect -LinkProtocol TCPIP -LinkHost "<-host->" 
-LinkName "1113@<-host->,51113@<-host->"
```

and leave the shell command empty.

Now when you run any command on the local machine, it will automatically connect to a remote kernel. Run `detach[]` to detach from the kernel. When you evaluate any other cell you will be reconnected to the same kernel (with same local variables).